# Creating a message box with ok and cancel asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

in my web page i have this javascript to show a message box to the user

```
  Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
        Dim lbl As New Label

        lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine &
           "window.alert('" + msg + "');" & Environment.NewLine &
           "document.location = 'Clinica.aspx';</script>"
        Page.Controls.Add(lbl)
    End Sub
```

and what i wanted to know is if it was possible to put in there an "ok" and a "cancel" button so in vb.net would be something like this

```
                  MsgBox(vbCritical _
                   & "Os dados da marcação actual foram alterados!" & vbCrLf _
                   & "Mudando a marcação selecciona irá perder as alteraçãoes" & vbCrLf _
                   & vbCrLf _
                   & "Deseja continuar?", _
                   vbOKCancel, _
                    "ATENÇÃO!")
```

im new to javascript and i wanted to know if something like this is possible, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), this does what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about js `confirm('Confirmation text')` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

So your code will run like:

```
 lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" & Environment.NewLine &
      "if(window.confirm('" + msg + "')) document.location = 'Clinica.aspx';</script>"
```

Comment: but how can i see outside the script that the user pressed ok or cancel ? like in the actual code that calls this message? is it simple or should i ask another question?

Comment: sry i really dont know anything about javascript xD

Comment: As you can see there's an `if` there, like this `if(confirm('blahblah')) { do stuff }` I actually included the code above, so the `document.tlocation` part runs only if the user clicks "OK"